# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes after kernel update

Tags: kernel, segmentation-fault

I have Ubuntu 14.04. After having updated the system to `kernel 3.13.0-49-generic`, I re-booted and now everything freezes! I cannot log in. (Keyboard and mouse do not work as well)

I found this line in my `kern.log` when I first rebooted after kernel update:

```
segfault at 0 ip 00007f2d1fabd0c8 sp 00007f2d02ef7500 error 6 in libcontent.so[7f2d1f178000+141f000]
```

This error appeared once in the first time I wanted to reboot after updating the kernel.

I came across [Google Chrome crashes the whole system - Ubuntu 14.04](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/zjjitIYfuxw).

And I uninstalled my chrome browser and rebooted again. But no luck.

Anything else that I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the question, the new kernel was causing me the problems, so I booted with my older kernel and everything is back to normal. The answer to this question helped:
[How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)
So first update grub, then reboot, while rebooting, press and hold Shift key. Then go to advanced options, and from there, select an older kernel version (kernel 3.13.0-36-generic in my case).